# Android Network Application connected to Amazon EC2

Tags: java, android, sockets, amazon-ec2, serversocket

I'm kind of new in this kind of development. To be short I'm working on a android app which sends a string to the cloud (I have a virtual server machine on Amazon), everything works well sending the string from my phone to the server machine, I print the string I'm sending and it works!. But when getting the response back from the server to my android app (I'm running it on my android phone) I don't get anything (The response should be a string + another string concatenated), that's it, easy right? But unfortunately I can't receive it back. I tested the server side and It's working properly (The amazon EC2). I'm not really sure if I can do what Im doing which is:

CREATING ransmission code to send the String by using a SOCKET TO SEND DATA TO THE CLOUD ON THE doInBackground() method from the AsyncTask class.
In the same method doInBackground I do the code to receive the response back by using a ServerSocket to receive the response back from the cloud.  Is it possible or do I need another thread or something like that?

Here is my code:

```
`import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import java.io.DataInputStream;
 import java.io.DataOutputStream;
 import java.net.*;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.view.View;


 public class ReadWebpageAsyncTask extends Activity {
private TextView textView;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    }

    private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) 
        {
            String response = "";               

            //Transmission
            try 
               {
                  Socket socket = new Socket("MyAmazonServerIp", 5678);
                  DataOutputStream salida = new DataOutputStream  (socket.getOutputStream());
                  salida.writeUTF("Llego Perfectamente");
                  socket.close();
                  salida.close();
               }
                  catch (Exception e) 
                      {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }

           //Final ends


           // Reception
            boolean ak=true;
            try 
            {
               ServerSocket ServerSock = new ServerSocket(7896);
                while(ak)
                  {
                    Socket cl=ServerSock.accept();
                    InetAddress ipC = cl.getInetAddress();

                    DataInputStream en= new DataInputStream(cl.getInputStream());
                    response= en.readUTF();
                    //response= response.toString();
                    ak=false;
                 }  
           }
           catch(Exception exp)
             {
               exp.printStackTrace();
             }
           // Reception ends 

           return response;

        } //doInBackground ends

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
          {
            textView.setText(result);
          }
    }

    public void readWebpage(View view) {
        DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
        task.execute(new String[] { "????" });

    }
 }`
```

I will really appreciate any help since I've been working on this for days and I have not been able to solve it. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

The way you are doing it can not work over a 3G or likely even a WiFi connection.  It can't work over 3G because the address your Amazon server sees is the address of the proxy/firewall on your cell provider's network.  No external application can open a socket directly to your phone.  Instead you need to send the response back over the same socket the phone created to send the initial message.

Over WiFi, it will not work because of the NAT translation likely going on with your WiFi firewall.

This is done for many reasons, not the least of which is data usage and security. Specifically, think about if your phone was publicly addressable to the entire Internet? It would constantly be getting hit with attempts to hack it.

So basically, just keep the original socket open and listen for a response on that socket and on your cloud server just send the response back over teh same socket you receive the request on.

Comment: Thank you very much Kaediil,

I really appreciate your help. Sorry for the late answer I was out of the city working, but I'm going to start working on it again. Thanks for your time again, best wishes for you!..

Alberto.

Comment: Kaediil, Thanks I have it working now... It sends strings from my phone to the remote pc as well as the phone receives strings from the remote pc. Now I'm trying to implement a file transfer (First, from the phone to the remote PC -The remote pc has a server app which sorts the text file- and send it back to the phone). Right now, the remote pc is receiving the file successfully and sort it. But when transmitting the file back to the phone I get an exception on the phone. I'm doing this over the same socket. Here is part of the phone app code: